# A LINQ query with grouping and filtering of special groups

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class...

```
class Document
{
    public int GroupID  { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    // more
}
```

... and a list of instances: `IEnumerable<Document> documents`. In a first step which runs object by object through this list those documents have been validated, which means: the property `Valid` will be `true` for some objects and `false` for other objects in the list.

Now in a second step I have to do the following:

- If for at least one document per document group (defined by all documents with the same `GroupID`) the flag `Valid` is `false` then set `Valid` to `false` for all documents of the group.

To do this I have created so far the following code fragment:

```
var q = from d in documents
        group d by d.GroupID;
// q is now of type IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Document>>

foreach (var dg in q) // dg = "document group", of type IGrouping<int, Document>
{
    if (dg.Any(d => !d.Valid))
    {
        foreach (var d in dg)
            d.Valid = false;
    }
}
```

I believe, this does what I want (I didn't test it until now, though) but not very efficiently.

Question: Is there a way to improve this code, especially to move the semantics of the `Any` method in the outer foreach loop "somehow" into the initial LINQ query, so that `q` only represents the groups which have at least one invalid document? (Also I am obviously not interested in groups which have only one element, so those groups could be filtered out as well.)

Thank you for suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
var q = from d in documents
        group d by d.GroupID into g
        where g.Count() > 1 && g.Any(d => !d.Valid)
        select g;

foreach (var dg in q)
{
    foreach (var d in dg)
    {
        d.Valid = false;
    }
}
```

The top part in fluent syntax would look like:

```
var q = documents.GroupBy(d => d.GroupID)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && g.Any(d => !d.Valid));
```

Comment: Yes, I think, that's exactly what I was looking for! Quite natural and straight-forward formulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to set the Valid flag to false if one of the documents is not Valid, you could try grabbing the list of the GroupId's who are not valid and then set all of the documents whose share a group with them to be invalid.  Sample code as follows:

```
//Find the invalid GroupIds.
var invalidIds = documents.Where(d => !d.IsValid).Select(p => p.GroupId).Distinct();

//invalidIds now holds the bad groupIds.
//So we can find out if each document's GroupId is an invalid one, and if it is, mark it as invalid.
documents.Where(d => invalidIds.Contains(d.GroupId)).ToList().ForEach(p => p.IsValid = false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks quite sophisticated! I have problems to compile because the extension method `ForEach` isn't known. Do I need an additional assembly or namespace? Or is it a .NET 4.0 feature? (I must stay in .NET 3.5 SP1 with this project.)

Comment: @Slauma - It all depends on what type of collection your documents object is. If it is a List<Document>, then the foreach extension method should work. If it is an IEnumberable<Document> or another type of collection, then there may not be a foreach extension method available. You would have to do documents.Where(d => invalidIds.Contains(d.GroupId)).ToList().ForEach(p => p.IsValid = false);

Comment: @Slauma - I updated my code sample.  I forgot that you need to cast to a List first.

Comment: @kevev22, Correl: OK, I see now, thank you! Interesting solution! But I think I'll go the other way since I have the feeling that the chain of `Distinct` and `Contains` might be too heavy operations for large lists (at least compared to the single query in Correl's answer).